# Perl - getting unexpected result while using print function

Tags: perl, printing

Hi I am trying to create a file with contents as given below

```
$outfile = `hostname`;
$txt = "\nHealth check results - ";
$txt .= `hostname`;
$txt .= "\n===========================================";
print "$txt";

# Create output file to store the HC results.

open $fh, '>', $outfile or die "Can't open $outfile \n";
print $fh $txt;
close ($fh)
```

the output comes like below

Health check results - XXHOSTNAMEXX

===========================================XXHOSTNAMEXX

why is the hostname getting printed twice, which I dont need the second time printing of hostname at the end.

Also I am trying to create filename as hostname as you see above in code, where it creates the file name as hostname, however I see a newline character is appended to the filename which I noticed while listing the files in the dir(using ls -ltr)(ie., the filename itlself is displayed with two lines - first line is hostname and an empty newline appended to the filename)

Comment: *"why is the hostname getting printed twice..."* It is difficult see why there would be a second hostname..Try insert single quotes in the `print` command to debug: `print "'$txt'"` What is the output from the `print` statement now, where are the single quotes in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the getting `hostname entermark` with `chomp()` function.

```
$outfile = `hostname`;

chomp $outfile;  #----> Need to chomp (Remove last entermark)

$txt = "\nHealth check results - ";

$txt .= $outfile; #----> Already you got the hostname hence just store $outfile 

$txt .= "\n===========================================";
print "$txt";

# Create output file to store the HC results.

open $fh, '>', $outfile or die "Can't write $outfile \n";
print $fh $txt;
close ($fh)
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
$outfile = `hostname`;
```

will run the `hostname` command and return *all* the data written to STDOUT, including the terminating EOL. This means you end up with a filename that include the terminating EOL character. What the filesystem does with that is OS dependent, but on Linux you will end up with a file that include the EOl character.

You can remove that with the `chomp`

```
$outfile = `hostname`;
chomp $outfile;
```

updated script looks like this

```
$outfile = `hostname`;
chomp $outfile;

$txt = "\nHealth check results - ";
$txt .= $outfile;
$txt .= "\n===========================================\n";
print "$txt";

# Create output file to store the HC results.

open $fh, '>', $outfile or die "Can't open $outfile \n";
print $fh $txt;
close ($fh) ;
```

I get this when I run it

```
Health check results - XXHOSTNAMEXX
===========================================
```

Comment: Excellent thanks!

Worked like charm,

One thing I noted was at the end of the below line a new line(\n) is mandatory, other wise I see the hostname printed second time at the end of line

`$txt .= "\n===========================================\n";`